# Heap Corruption in release mode only

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is a printing thread that prints the statistic of my currently running program

```
void StatThread::PrintStat(){
clock_t now = 0;
UINT64 oneMega = 1<<20;
const char* CUnique = 0;;
const char* CInserted = 0;;
while((BytesInserted<=fileSize.QuadPart)&&flag){
    Sleep(1000);
    now = clock();
    CUnique = FormatNumber(nUnique);
    CInserted = FormatNumber(nInserted);
    printf("[ %.2f%%] %u / %u dup %.2f%% @ %.2fM/s %.2fMB/s %3.2f%% %uMB\n",
        (double)BytesInserted*100/(fileSize.QuadPart),
        nUnique,nInserted,(nInserted-nUnique)*100/(double)nInserted,
        ((double)nInserted/1000000)/((now - start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC),
        ((double)BytesInserted/oneMega)/((now - start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC),
        cpu.GetCpuUtilization(NULL),cpu.GetProcessRAMUsage (true));
    if(BytesInserted==fileSize.QuadPart)
        flag=false;
}
delete[] CUnique;    //would have worked with memory leak if commented out
delete[] CInserted;  // crash at here! heap corruption 
}
```

This is FormatNumber that returns a pointer to a char array

```
const char* StatThread::FormatNumber(const UINT64& number) const{
char* result = new char[100];
result[0]='\0';
_i64toa_s(number,result,100,10);
DWORD nDigits = ceil(log10((double)number));
result[nDigits] = '\0';
if(nDigits>3){
    DWORD nComma=0;
    if(nDigits%3==0)
        nComma = (nDigits/3) -1;
    else
        nComma = nDigits/3;
    char* newResult = new char[nComma+nDigits+1];
    newResult[nComma+nDigits]='\0';
    for(DWORD i=1;i<=nComma+1;i++){
        memcpy(newResult+strlen(newResult)-i*3-(i-1),result+strlen(result)-i*3,3);
        if(i!=nComma+1){
            *(newResult+strlen(newResult)-4*i) = ',';   
        }
    }
    delete[] result; 
    return newResult;
}
return result;
}
```

What is really weird was that it crashed only in release mode because of a heap corruption, but run smoothly in debug mode. I've already checked everywhere and found no obvious memory leaks, and even Memory Leak Detector said so too.

```
Visual Leak Detector Version 2.2.3 installed.
The thread 0x958 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
No memory leaks detected.
Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
The program '[5232] Caching.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

However, when run in release mode,it threw an error that said my program stop working and I clicked on debug, it pointed to the line that caused the heap corruption.

```
The thread 0xe4c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000770E6AE2 (ntdll.dll) in Caching.exe:          0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x000000007715D430).
```

If I commented out this line, it worked fine but Memory Leak Detector would have complained about memory leak! I don't understand how to cause a heap corruption when there was no memory leaks, (at least that's what the Leak Detector said). Please help, Thank you in advance.

Edit:
Heap corruption was fixed, because in the very last iteration, I still copied 3 byes to the front instead of whatever is leftover. Thank you all for helps!

```
const char* StatThread::FormatNumber(const UINT64& number) const{
char* result = new char[100];
result[0]='\0';
_ui64toa_s(number,result,100,10);
DWORD nDigits = (DWORD)ceil(log10((double)number));
if(number%10==0){
    nDigits++;
}
result[nDigits] = '\0';
if(nDigits>3){
    DWORD nComma=0;
    if(nDigits%3==0)
        nComma = (nDigits/3) -1;
    else
        nComma = nDigits/3;
    char* newResult = new char[nComma+nDigits+1];
    DWORD lenNewResult = nComma+nDigits;
    DWORD lenResult = nDigits;
    for(DWORD i=1;i<=nComma+1;i++){
        if(i!=nComma+1){
            memcpy(newResult+lenNewResult-4*i+1,result+lenResult-3*i,3);
            *(newResult+lenNewResult-4*i) = ',';    
        }
        else{
            memcpy(newResult,result,lenNewResult-4*(i-1));
        }
    }
    newResult[nComma+nDigits] = '\0';
    delete[] result; 
    return newResult;
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: This is a really silly way to add commas to a number. Firstly, the `nDigits > 3` check for an unsigned number can just be done using `number > 999`.  Once you have the number as a string, just work from right to left, copying the text and inserting a comma every three digits. Copy it this way to the tail of the buffer. When done do a `memmmove` to move the string to the beginning of the buffer. 100 bytes is enough to do this all in one buffer for a 64 bit integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to be blunt, but the code to "format" a string is **horrible**.

First of all, you pass in an unsigned 64-bit int value, which you formatted as a signed value instead. If you claim to sell bananas, you shouldn't give your customers plantains instead.

But what's worse is that what you do return (when you don't crash) isn't even right. If a user passes in 0, well, then you return nothing at all. And if a user passes in 1000000 you return 100,000 and if he passes in 10000000 you return 1,000,000. Oh well, what's a factor of 10 for some numbers between friends? ;)

These, along with the crash, are symptoms of the crazy pointer arithmetic your code does. Now, to the bugs:

First of all, when you allocate 'newResult' you leave the buffer in a very weird state. The first nComma + nDigits bytes are random values, followed by a NULL. You then call strlen on that buffer. The result of that strlen can be any number between 0 and nComma + nDigits, because any one of the nComma + nDigit characters may contain the null byte, which will cause strlen to terminate prematurely. In other words, the code is non-deterministic after that point.

Sidenote: If you're curious why it works in debug builds, it's because the compiler and the debug version of the runtime libraries try to help you catch bugs by initializing memory for you. In Visual C++ the fill mask is usually 0xCC. This made sure that the bug in your strlen() was covered up in debug builds.

Fixing that bug is pretty simple: simply initialize the buffer with spaces, followed by a NULL.

```
char* newResult = new char[nComma+nDigits+1];
memset(newResult, ' ', nComma+nDigits);
newResult[nComma+nDigits]='\0';
```

But there's one more bug. Let's try to format the number 1152921504606846975 which should become 1,152,921,504,606,846,975. Let's see what some of fancy pointer arithmetic operations give us:

```
memcpy(newResult + 25 - 3 - 0, result + 19 - 3, 3)
*(newResult + 25 - 4) = ','
memcpy(newResult + 25 - 6 - 1, result + 19 - 6, 3)
*(newResult + 25 - 8) = ','
memcpy(newResult + 25 - 9 - 2, result + 19 - 9, 3)
*(newResult + 25 - 12) = ','
memcpy(newResult + 25 - 12 - 3, result + 19 - 12, 3)
*(newResult + 25 - 16) = ','
memcpy(newResult + 25 - 15 - 4, result + 19 - 15, 3)
*(newResult + 25 - 20) = ','
memcpy(newResult + 25 - 18 - 5, result + 19 - 18, 3)
*(newResult + 25 - 24) = ','
memcpy(newResult + 25 - 21 - 6, result + 19 - 21, 3)
```

As you can see, your very last operation copies data 2 bytes *before* the beginning of the buffer you allocated. This is because you assume that you will always be copying 3 characters. Of course, that's not always the case.

Frankly, I don't think your version of FormatNumber should be fixed. all that pointer arithmetic and calculations are bugs waiting to happen. Here's the version I wrote, which you can use if you want. I consider it much more sane, but your mileage may vary:

```
const char *StatThread::FormatNumber(UINT64 number) const
{
    // The longest 64-bit unsigned integer 0xFFFFFFFF is equal
    // to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. That's 26 characters
    // so our buffer will be big enough to hold two of those
    // although, technically, we only need 6 extra characters
    // at most.
    const int buflen = 64;

    char *result = new char[buflen];
    int cnt = -1, idx = buflen;

    do
    {
        cnt++;

        if((cnt != 0) && ((cnt % 3) == 0))
            result[--idx] = ',';

        result[--idx] = '0' + (number % 10);
        number = number / 10;
    } while(number != 0);

    cnt = 0;

    while(idx != buflen)
        result[cnt++] = result[idx++];

    result[cnt] = 0;

    return result;
}
```

P.S.: The "*off by a factor of 10*" thing is left as an exerise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you for the criticism, turned out it was because of the copying 3 bytes in the very last iteration that caused the overflow. Thank you again

Comment: There are two instances of corruption: one is the last iteration of the memcpy in the loop, the other can be caused by the use of strlen() against 'newResult' which is non-deterministic. Sorry if I came across as a bit too harsh, but it was to drive through the point that you shouldn't use your version of FormatNumber. Instead of rewriting it, I would *strongly* suggest you use the drop-in replacement version I provided.

Answer (score 1):

At the line

```
DWORD nDigits = ceil(log10((double)number));
```

you need three digits for 100 but log 100 = 2. This means that you allocating one too few characters for `char* newResult = new char[nComma+nDigits+1];`. This means that the end of your heap cell is being overwritten which is resulting in the heap corruption you are seeing. Debug heap allocation may be more forgiving which is why the crash is only in debug mode.

Comment: Sharp eyes! I've fixed it, but I don't think that's case because first of all, the number to be the exact a power of 10 is rare, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Heap corruption is usually caused by overwriting the heap data structures. There is a lot of use of "result" and "newResult" without good boundary checking. When you do a debug build, the whole alignment changes and by chance the error doesnt happen.

I would start by adding checks like this:

```
DWORD nDigits = ceil(log10((double)number));
if(nDigits>=100){printf("error\n");exit(1);}
result[nDigits] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things in your `StatThread::PrintStat` function.

This is a memory leak if the loop body executes more than once. You would reassign these pointers without calling `delete[]` for the previous values.

```
while((BytesInserted<=fileSize.QuadPart)&&flag){
    ...
    CUnique = FormatNumber(nUnique);
    CInserted = FormatNumber(nInserted);
    ...
}
```

Is this supposed to be an assignment `=` or a comparison `==`?

```
if(BytesInserted=fileSize.QuadPart)
    flag=false;
```

**Edit to add:**

In your `StatThread::FormatNumber` function this statement adds a null terminator to the end of the block but the previous chars may contain garbage (`new` doesn't zero allocated memory). The subsequest calls to `strlen()` may return an unexpected length.

```
newResult[nComma+nDigits]='\0';
```

Comment: OMG, I didn't see that, ***if(BytesInserted=fileSize.QuadPart)***, it's supposed to be a comparison, fixed, but the same error occurred. I'll dig into what you guys said, Thanks